# Using case_when to fill out a string

Tags: r

I am trying to use `case_when` in order to `pad` out a string in R, dependent on the string length.

I take the following 3 examples with lengths 11, 12 and 13:

```
V1                    V2
74300000330          00074300000330
811693200042         08011693200042
8829999820128        88029999820128
```

`V1` is the column I am trying to match with `V2`

The first row in `V1` has 11 digits, if the row has 11 digits then add 3 zeros at the begining of the number.

I have tried the following code without any luck (I have also tried it with `paste0()`);

```
df %>% 
  mutate(col3 = case_when(length(col1) == 11 ~ str_pad(14, width = 3, pad = "0")))
```

The second has 12 digits, so I should add one zero at the begining of the number and then another zero between (counting from the left) the first digit and (counting from right) 11th digit, so row 2 would go from `81169...` to `0801169...`.

The third row has 13 digits so I should paste a zero between the (counting from the left) 2nd digit and (counting from the right) the 11th digit. So the begining of the sequence goes from `88299` to `880299`.

The total number of digits in the sequence should be exactly 14.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 
56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 
61L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 
66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 68L, 
68L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 
71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 
71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 
72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 74L, 
74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
81L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 
84L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 
93L, 93L, 93L, 94L, 94L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 97L, 
97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 
104L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 106L, 
107L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 
113L, 113L, 113L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 
115L, 116L, 116L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 
119L, 119L, 119L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 
122L, 122L, 122L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L), .Label = c("11114110010", 
"11114110022", "11114110029", "11114110036", "11114110210", "11114110230", 
"11114110261", "11114110271", "11114110281", "11114110291", "11114110316", 
"11114110526", "11780900029", "11780900050", "11780900660", "11780900661", 
"12451500878", "12451567602", "12550000033", "12550000365", "12550000366", 
"12550000367", "12550000371", "12550000376", "12550000377", "12550000384", 
"12550000388", "12550000392", "12550000393", "12550000397", "12550000401", 
"12550000402", "12550000538", "12550006763", "12550006764", "12550020040", 
"12550020042", "12550020043", "12550020044", "12550020188", "12550020204", 
"12550020212", "12550090015", "12800046631", "12800063141", "12800070612", 
"14300002922", "14300002923", "14300002924", "14300002925", "14300002934", 
"14300002940", "14300002941", "14300002942", "14300003300", "14300004091", 
"14300004296", "14300004299", "14300004301", "14300004648", "14300004650", 
"14300004651", "14300070522", "15543760143", "15543760145", "15543760186", 
"15543760235", "15543760253", "17089302817", "17103800044", "17103800047", 
"17103800048", "17103800053", "17103800056", "17103800058", "17103800059", 
"17103801173", "17103801175", "17232305018", "17447100091", "17510100575", 
"17510100576", "17510121064", "17510121065", "17510181458", "17732447059", 
"17762300048", "17762300060", "18903644280", "19955508003", "19955508050", 
"19955508060", "19955508061", "19955508531", "19955508534", "19955508758", 
"19955508792", "19955508800", "19955508801", "19955508832", "19955508992", 
"19955509803", "19955538570", "19955538696", "19955538725", "19955538792", 
"21291912261", "21780900078", "22550081121", "22550081122", "22800025406", 
"22800030050", "24300070590", "25543760142", "25543760521", "29955539550", 
"31291912240", "39955508520", "41114110525", "57103800060", "74300000330", 
"8,11693E+11", "8,83E+12"), class = "factor"), col2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 
53L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 
66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 
66L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 
70L, 70L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 
71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 
71L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 
73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 76L, 
77L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 
83L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 
88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 94L, 94L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
101L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 
105L, 105L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 
109L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 
112L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 
114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 116L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 118L, 
118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 119L, 119L, 
119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 121L, 
123L, 122L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 127L, 124L, 126L, 126L, 
127L, 127L, 125L), .Label = c("00011114110010", "00011114110022", 
"00011114110029", "00011114110036", "00011114110210", "00011114110230", 
"00011114110261", "00011114110271", "00011114110281", "00011114110291", 
"00011114110316", "00011114110526", "00011780900029", "00011780900050", 
"00011780900660", "00011780900661", "00012451500878", "00012451567602", 
"00012550000033", "00012550000365", "00012550000366", "00012550000367", 
"00012550000371", "00012550000376", "00012550000377", "00012550000384", 
"00012550000388", "00012550000392", "00012550000393", "00012550000397", 
"00012550000401", "00012550000402", "00012550000538", "00012550006763", 
"00012550006764", "00012550020040", "00012550020042", "00012550020043", 
"00012550020044", "00012550020188", "00012550020204", "00012550020212", 
"00012550090015", "00012800046631", "00012800063141", "00012800070612", 
"00014300002922", "00014300002923", "00014300002924", "00014300002925", 
"00014300002934", "00014300002940", "00014300002941", "00014300002942", 
"00014300003300", "00014300004091", "00014300004296", "00014300004299", 
"00014300004301", "00014300004648", "00014300004650", "00014300004651", 
"00014300070522", "00015543760143", "00015543760145", "00015543760186", 
"00015543760235", "00015543760253", "00017089302817", "00017103800044", 
"00017103800047", "00017103800048", "00017103800053", "00017103800056", 
"00017103800058", "00017103800059", "00017103801173", "00017103801175", 
"00017232305018", "00017447100091", "00017510100575", "00017510100576", 
"00017510121064", "00017510121065", "00017510181458", "00017732447059", 
"00017762300048", "00017762300060", "00018903644280", "00019955508003", 
"00019955508050", "00019955508060", "00019955508061", "00019955508531", 
"00019955508534", "00019955508758", "00019955508792", "00019955508800", 
"00019955508801", "00019955508832", "00019955508992", "00019955509803", 
"00019955538570", "00019955538696", "00019955538725", "00019955538792", 
"00021291912261", "00021780900078", "00022550081121", "00022550081122", 
"00022800025406", "00022800030050", "00024300070590", "00025543760142", 
"00025543760521", "00029955539550", "00031291912240", "00039955508520", 
"00041114110525", "00057103800060", "00074300000330", "08011693200041", 
"08011693200042", "88029999819907", "88029999820074", "88029999820083", 
"88029999820128"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -513L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues here. Your columns appear to be factors, which can create confusing problems when you apply string functions to them. You want them to be character, not factor. The correct way to check the length of a string is with `nchar` (spoiler alert: does not work with factor data!).

Your rules for padding seem a little arbitrary, but the following should work. For padding "within" the digit string, `gsub` and regular expressions work wonders.

```
df2 <- mutate_at(df, vars(col1, col2), as.character) %>% 
  mutate(col3 = case_when(
    nchar(col1) == 11 ~ str_pad(col1, width = 14, pad = '0'),
    nchar(col1) == 12 ~ gsub('(\\d)(\\d+)', '0\\10\\2', col1),
    nchar(col1) == 13 ~ gsub('(\\d\\d)(\\d+)', '\\10\\2', col1),
    T ~ col1
  ))

  col1          col3          
  <chr>         <chr>         
1 74300000330   00074300000330
2 811693200042  08011693200042
3 8829999820128 88029999820128
```

Comment: This seems to work great on the larger data. Only 18 "non-matches" out of 20,000. Thanks!